# What's actually going on with this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, null

Here's where my confusion starts, so a null pointer is declared first. Then selection is executed running whatever input was given then the function randomEncounter comes.

```
 cout << "1) Move, 2) Rest, 3) View Stats, 4) Quit: ";
            cin >> selection;

            Monster* monster = 0;
            switch( selection )
            {
            case 1:
                gameMap.movePlayer();

                // Check for a random encounter.  This function
                // returns a null pointer if no monsters are
                // encountered.
                monster = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();

                // 'monster' not null, run combat simulation.
                if( monster != 0 )
```

So next when the function goes through, is

```
//refering to the once null pointer and now modifies something real?
monster = new Monster
```

Is

```
0 = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();
```

Or is it pointing to nothing instead of the actually value of zero, and waits patiently to have something to point to? So

```
0 = null;
```

Until the function is ran: Here's the function

```
Monster* Map::checkRandomEncounter()
{
    int roll = Random(0, 20);

    Monster* monster = 0;

    if( roll <= 5 )
    {
        // No encounter, return a null pointer.
        return 0;
    }
    else if(roll >= 6 && roll <= 10)
    {
        monster = new Monster("Orc", 10, 8, 200, 1, 
            "Short Sword", 2, 7);

        cout << "You encountered an Orc!" << endl;
        cout << "Prepare for battle!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

So does when there is an encounter:

```
monster = new Monster();
```

Does this modify the once null pointer to a now real object, or does this make a completely new object? I'm so confused how all this links together. Also in the function there is a second

```
Monster* monster = 0;
```

Where is this one used, and how does it get back to the calling function that there was an encounter. I realize its somehow going back through the pointer but definitely need some clarity

Comment: Why is this getting up votes?  This is sounds like not understanding the basic functionality of pointers (and possibly scoping) unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Why is your comment getting upvoted? Sounding like something is not the same as reading and understanding what the question is asking. Also this isn't constructive, sounds like some people here use this site more like a social networking site instead of a learning enviroment

Comment: I gave OP a +1 in hopes to keep things neutral and keep flames away. So as to not discourage them. However, Aggieboy does have a point. It is likely you (@OP) `may` learn more on `cplusplus.com's` tutorial than from an answer but just wait a while and see if there is a good reply/explanation that suits your needs. You will likely get a good one but not a full in depth tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in the posted code are nothing if not self explanatory.

The caller side simply starts with a `Monster` pointer that is initially NULL(0) (deliberately pointing to no object), and assigns it the return value from `checkRandomEncounter()` if `selection` is `1`. If that function return a non-null address, it means a `Monster` has been returned and a specific course of action in response shall be undertaken.

```
// Check for a random encounter.  This function
// returns a null pointer if no monsters are
// encountered.
monster = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();

// 'monster' not null, run combat simulation.
if( monster != 0 ) ...
```

Regarding `checkRandomEncounter()`

```
if( roll <= 5 )
{
    // No encounter, return a null pointer.
    return 0;
}
```

So the function returns a null pointer if the roll is below 5, otherwise if it is between 6 and 10, then allocate a new `Monster` and return a pointer to that.

```
else if(roll >= 6 && roll <= 10)
{
    monster = new Monster("Orc", 10, 8, 200, 1, 
        "Short Sword", 2, 7);

    cout << "You encountered an Orc!" << endl;
    cout << "Prepare for battle!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

And though not shown, there had better be some code to handle what happens when the roll is between 11 and 20, I'm guessing it is likely different monster types being generated, each with different random ranges. (just a shot in the dark there).

Regardless, if it were possible or the author to be more specific in what is going on, I'm pressed to see how. If it still isn't clear, you need to spend time learning basic pointer nuances in C++ prior to dissecting this further.

Finally, if the variable *names* are confusing you, does it help at all to know the `monster` pointer variable in the main code has *nothing* to do with the one in `checkRandomEncounter()` ? Apart from the latter being used for calculating a return value that will eventually be assigned to the former due to the code structure, they are *entirely* unrelated, different pointers.

Comment: You pretty much answered it pretty well, cleared some things up. And yes there are more pieces that go with this, especially to finish the other options for roll. But another question, so monster = new Monster returns something to the originally null pointer which is now a new object with new values

Comment: @Jcodin yes, and my last paragraph should hopeful explain that further. If the names are briefing you, understand the two pointers are *different* variables. One is in the main code, the other in another function, used to calculate the return value that will eventually be assigned to the former.

Comment: Could you answer though why is Monster* monster redeclared in the function as well, how would monster know to return it to the calling function instead of that one?

Comment: You have to put the return result *somewhere*. They could have skipped the output stuff and simply returnd `new Monster(... blah... )`. Check at the bottom of the function and you'll find the address held in the local `monster` variable is being returned, then assigned to the *callers* `monster` variable.

Comment: Or is the flow of it like so: check the random encounter, then send the return to the null pointer in the function, which re initializes the calling monster to change to non null?

Comment: so the redeclaration is just for scoping purposes?

Comment: @Jcodin yes. Change it to something else in the check-function You'll see. (sry, had to eat dinner).

Comment: Are you using this as a learning tool to understand pointers? If so, all well and good. But just be mindful that modern C++ is steering away from using raw pointers. Is there any chance you could go to C++11? (I'm assuming you're not due to not using nullptr, etc.) @WhozCraig, your answer is comprehensive, but I'm sure as a beginner I would've been confused by the statement that the two pointers are completely unrelated (although it's true) as they point to the same Monster :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the pointer for the other side of the if (or you haven't included the last two lines which i would assume to be

```
return monster;
}
```

from the gameMap.checkRandomEncounter method.

Also you shouldn't be printing stuff out in that method - just focus on checking if the encounter is triggered and then this affect the flow of the game.

Comment: you must return the pointer that's the issue - a pointer is just a bucket that holds an address.  if you don't return the contents of the bucket it can't pass through.

Comment: ie to create a monster you could do something like: 'Monster* createMonster(void){ Monster* m=null; if( something) { m = new Monster(..);}else {// do nothing with m } return m;}